# How do I put a password on an individual Dropbox folder?

Tags: dropbox

We have a group of people working within the same Dropbox at work. I want to create a link for each worker to the traceability he/she is working with.

For example, Piet is using form 1,2,6; Jan is using 4,5,8. I want to put a password on Jan's folder so that Piet can't use her forms.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to password protect the folders. You simply need to share the folders relevant to a specific person only, and no more folders than that.

You can send sharing invites to different people, so why not send invites from different folders instead of sharing from every folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the dropbox on user level and allow the sync / view to particual folders only.

I hope that will work for you.

Regards

Suyash